# How can be character pointer array function implemented?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I try to write a function which returns a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters, which are stored in "characters", removed. e.g.

```
  strip("-__-ceng_240---__,," , "_-,") 

  return "ceng_240"
```

Here is my code, but it doesn't work. I think I have little problems, but I cannot find them.

```
char* strip(char* string, char* characters) {

    int i,j,k=0;

    char* astring = malloc((strlen(string)+1));

    for(i=0;string[i]!='\0';i++) {
        for(j=0;characters[j]!='\0';j++) {
            if(string[i]==characters[j])
                continue;
            else if(string[i]!=characters[j]) {
                astring[k] = string[i];
                k++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    astring[k] = '\0';
    astring = realloc(astring,strlen(astring));

    return astring;
}
```

Comment: Debugger.......................

Comment: The logic is severely broken.  Try to come up with a design *first*, and *then* code it.  Also, don't `malloc` an over-sized string up front and then shrink it. Instead, you just need to find the start and stop indices.  Then you can `malloc` the exact length needed, and copy the desired portion of the string to it.

Comment: You shouldn't call realloc like this.  If for some reason it fails, you have lost the pointer to the original memory block.

Comment: your realloc is too short

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call this trim== trim left & trim right
Like this working sample:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

char* trim_left(char* s, char* p) {
    char*q;
    while (*s){
        q = p;
        while (*q){
            if (*s != *q)q++; else { s++; break; }
        }
        if (!*q)break;
    }
    return s;
}
char* trim_right(char* s, char* p) {
    char *r = s;
    char*q;
    while (*s) s++;
    s--;
    while (s != r){
        q = p;
        while (*q){
            if (*s != *q)q++; else { s--; break; }
        }
        if (!*q)break;
    }
    s++;
    *s = 0;
    return r;
}
char* trim(char* s, char* p) {
    return  trim_left(trim_right(s, p), p);
}

int main(){
    char str[] = "-__-ceng_240---__,,";
    char *p = trim(str, "_-,");
    printf("%s", p); //ceng_240
    //return "ceng_240"
}
```

another way usin helper function is_trimchar:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

char trim_chars[] = "_-,";

int is_trimchar(char c){
    char *p = trim_chars;
    do{
        if (*p == c)return 1;
        p++;
    } while (*p);
    return 0;
}


char* trim_left(char* s) {
    while (*s)
        if (is_trimchar(*s)) s++; else break;
    return s;
}

char* trim_right(char* s) {
    char *r = s;
    while (*s) s++;
    s--;
    while (s != r)
        if (is_trimchar(*s)) s--; else break;
    s++;
    *s = 0;
    return r;
}

char* trim(char* s) {
    return  trim_left(trim_right(s));
}

int main(){
    char str[] = "-__-ceng_240---__,,";
    char *p = trim(str);
    printf("%s", p); //ceng_240
    //return "ceng_240"
}
```

Comment: Note that this implementation does mangle the input string -- which may or may not be the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

try:char* astring =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(string)+1));

Comment: Please provide a little explanation to your answers if you can.

Comment: Note that in straight C.... it is not necessary or advisable to cast the output of malloc()...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* strip(char* string, char* characters) {
    int i, j, k;
    char *p = string + strspn(string, characters);//skip front
    char *astring = malloc(strlen(p)+1);

    for(j=i=0; p[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        astring[j++] = p[i];//copy
    }
    astring[j] = '\0';
    for(k = j -1; k >= 0; --k){//delete from tail
        if(strchr(characters, astring[k]))
            astring[k] = '\0';
        else
            break;
    }
    astring = realloc(astring, strlen(astring) + 1);//need +1
    return astring;
}
int main(void){
    char *result = strip("-__-ceng_240---__,," , "_-,");
    printf("'%s'\n", result);
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is at issue here... with unique `characters` in the list and `strlen(characters) > 1` the code will always copy all of the passed `string` to `astring`...  Here are a couple `printf`'s embedded into your original code that will illustrate:

```
char* strip(char* string, char* characters) {

    int i,j,k=0;

    char* astring = malloc((strlen(string)+1));

    for(i=0;string[i]!='\0';i++) {
        for(j=0;characters[j]!='\0';j++) {
            if(string[i]==characters[j])
                continue;
            else if(string[i]!=characters[j]) {
                printf("string[%d],characters[%d]: %c,%c\n",
                        i, j, string[i], characters[j]);
                astring[k] = string[i];
                k++;
                printf("astring: %s\n", astring);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    astring[k] = '\0';
    astring = realloc(astring,strlen(astring));

    return astring;
}
```

Output of this is:

```
string[0],characters[0]: -,_
astring: -
string[1],characters[1]: _,-
astring: -_
string[2],characters[1]: _,-
astring: -__
string[3],characters[0]: -,_
astring: -__-
string[4],characters[0]: c,_
astring: -__-c
string[5],characters[0]: e,_
astring: -__-ce
string[6],characters[0]: n,_
astring: -__-cen
string[7],characters[0]: g,_
astring: -__-ceng
string[8],characters[1]: _,-
astring: -__-ceng_
string[9],characters[0]: 2,_
astring: -__-ceng_2
string[10],characters[0]: 4,_
astring: -__-ceng_24
string[11],characters[0]: 0,_
astring: -__-ceng_240
string[12],characters[0]: -,_
astring: -__-ceng_240-
string[13],characters[0]: -,_
astring: -__-ceng_240--
string[14],characters[0]: -,_
astring: -__-ceng_240---
string[15],characters[1]: _,-
astring: -__-ceng_240---_
string[16],characters[1]: _,-
astring: -__-ceng_240---__
string[17],characters[0]: ,,_
astring: -__-ceng_240---__,
string[18],characters[0]: ,,_
astring: -__-ceng_240---__,,
-__-ceng_240---__,,
```

Your logic is not constructed to copy to `astring` only if *all* `characters` do not match.  Here is a fix with minimal changes:

```
char* strip(char* string, char* characters) {

    int i,j,k=0;

    char* astring = malloc((strlen(string)+1));

    for(i=0;string[i]!='\0';i++) {
        for(j=0;characters[j]!='\0';j++)
            if(string[i]==characters[j])
                break;
        if(characters[j])
            continue;
        astring[k] = string[i];
        k++;
    }
    astring[k] = '\0';
    astring = realloc(astring,strlen(astring));

    return astring;
}
```

There are still several things that we need to do in this function to make it robust...

One important thing to do when using dynamic memory allocation is to check the result of `malloc` and `realloc` and bail if you run out of memory.

To save time, you likely want to get rid of the `realloc`.  One way to do this would be to make two passes, or if you are not concerned so much about memory, you could `calloc` and drop both the `realloc` and `astring[k] = '\0'`.

Using `malloc` like this seems to me to be a memory leak just waiting to happen.  So, better is if you could pass the result by reference and hand the decision on what to do with memory back to the caller -- then the caller can allocate on stack or do whatever it likes.

Note that the result will also remove the "_" in the middle of the string.... if that is not what you want, here is my version with all of the above taken into consideration:

```
char *strip(char *src, char chars[], char dest[])
{
        char *c;
        while (*src) {
            c=chars;
            while (*c && *c!=*src)
                ++c;
            if (*c)
                ++src;
            else
                break;
        }
        char *x = src + strlen(src);
        while (src <= --x) {
            c=chars;
            while (*c && *c!=*x)
                ++c;
            if (!*c)
                break;
        }
        size_t n = x - src + 1;
        strncpy(dest, src, n);
        dest[n]='\0';
        return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use strspn() to find the valid starting point, then reverse the remaining string (into a temporary buffer) and again find the position using strspn().
With both results you can copy out the correct range from the source string into new memory using strndup().
Its not the efficientest way but its a way ;-)